# Program taking longer time in kernel mode

Tags: c

I have the following code files :
code-1.c :

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{
  unsigned int i,j;
  while(1)
    {
      j = 1;
      for(i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
          j = j*i;
          printf("%d\n", j);
        }
    }
}
```

code-2.c :

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{
  unsigned int i;
  int count = 0;
  struct timeval tv;

  while(1)
    {
      for(i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
          gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
          printf("%u sec, %u usec\n", tv.tv_sec, tv.tv_usec);
        }
      count++;
      printf("round %d complete\n", count);
    }
}
```

I ran cat /proc/${pid}/stat after running both the commands and got the following output:
 **code-2.c :** 
31055 (prog name) S 29727 31055 29727 34867 31055 4194304 75 0 0 0 3502 13606

**code-1.c:** 
31046 (prog name) S 29644 31046 29644 34844 31046 4194304 71 0 0 0 5057 21225

The 14th field is the user time and the 15th field is the kernel time. 
So code-2.c spent **13606** and code-1.c spent **21225** in kernel mode.
I ran both the code at the same time.
code-2.c has the function call gettimeofday so it's expected that it runs for more time in kernel mode. But the numbers are the opposite. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: `has the function call gettimeofday so it's expected that it runs for more time in kernel mode` why? What if `printf` spends more time in kernel mode then `gettimeofday`?

Comment: Sounds like you are just taking a snapshot of the stats. That's not conclusive as it's possible/likely that one program may have had more scheduling time than the other at the time of the snapshot. It would be better to have the code exactly the same except for the call to `gettimeofday` (or some other small variant) and to get the stats after or at the point the code is about to complete.

Comment: Re-write the code so that it ends and simply use [time](https://linux.die.net/man/1/time) to get the system  time of the complete program execution. That would be a more accurate measurement than taking a snapshot.

Comment: time is a good candidate for vdso. gettimeofday probably does not do a syscall.